# Sitecore Glass.Mapper.Sc vs Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Hi Fellow Sitecoryians ,

I'm in the process of upgrading a website sitting on Sitecore 7.1 rev140130 webforms to Sitecore 8.2rev160729 MVC-5 / Webforms hybrid. I require to keep the old content running. Because this is just an upgrade of the backend. But plan to start developing in MVC for all new components etc. I will phase out the old web forms as content pages change. This requirement is pushed on me by the business.

The old site used Glass Mapper to generate and map content from sitecore. Using the old Glass.Mapper.Sc.CasteWindsor v3.2.1.21 via t4 scripts in TDS.

I looked over the Glass homepage. Where is states that Glass.Mapper.Sc is all that you require now. But there are conflicting tutorials out there stating you need to install the MVC-4 or MVC-5. I figured I would ignore them for now and stick to the Glass suggested install.

Trouble is that the old Model properties are tagged with attributes like 
[SitecoreId] & [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Language)]

Which don't seem to be in the Glass.Mapper.Sc library. The only reference I can find of these attributes in the available nugets packages. Is the Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core package.

I tried to install that package in the models project. Just to see this :

> Start package installation to project [project].Logic.Models
>   Installation failed. Rolling back...
>   Error: Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core 4.2.1.189' is not > compatible with 'Glass.Mapper.Sc 4.3.1.194 constraint: Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core (≥ > 4.3.1.194)'.
>   Installation finished.

I feel like I might be making a mistake if I down-grade the Glass.Mapper.Sc so I can install the Core library. I might be shooting myself in the foot later on. Because I still have to install WFFM and Social Connection Module being replace with the internal sc8 social components..

My understanding was that the new Glass.Mapper.Sc package should cover all my needs.

So should I down grade and try and use the older version with the Core libraries?

Or should I refactor the models to use a new attribute system. What ever that may be?

(Keep in mind there are around 50+ models in the project. So it's not something that I would like to have  to do .. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glass Mapper was significantly changed in version 4 and the biggest change was the removal and reliance on Castle Windsor. A list of the changes were listed in the [release blog post](http://www.glass.lu/Blog/GlassV4).

The Nuget package/installer has also been changed so there is now only a single Nuget package instead of the several which you previously had to install. To support this, the Nuget installer checks for the presence of `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` and `System.Web.Mvc`:

> To make things simpler V4 uses a Powershell script to decided which references to add to your project, it checks both the Sitecore.Kernel version and the System.Web.Mvc version and then installs the appropriate Glass.Mapper.Sc and Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc assembly.

My suggestion would be to remove the old V3 assemblies and Nuget references, make sure the above 2 DLLs are correctly referenced in your project(s) and then install Glass V4 Nuget to those projects again.

The [`SitecoreId`](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/Configuration/Attributes/SitecoreIdAttribute.cs) and [`SitecoreInfo`](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/Configuration/Attributes/SitecoreInfoAttribute.cs) attributes are still in the `Glass.Mapper.Sc` library, the Core library has been removed/refactored. I don't believe this namespace has changed since V3 but make sure you are using the **GlassV3Header.tt** file and the `using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes` namespace is correct in that file.

https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/tds-codegen/blob/master/Sitecore.Master/Code%20Generation%20Templates/GlassV3Header.tt#L32

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I didn't need to change the generation scripts (at this point in time) 
I did manage to find a old reference to the CastleWindsor in the models project, and I didn't have a reference to the system.web.mvc in another project. So I think that was throwing me off. 
Plus Nuget for some reason was not tagging the Glass.Mapper.Sc package as containing the references I needed. Nuget would only return the Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core package.

Comment: Love how enter auto summits these comments too StackOverflow.... :/ I assume the nuget package didn't see the references based on the powershell scripts working that out for you. So there would be no connection in the nuget search indexing. Thanks again for pointing that out.

Comment: I've found it safer/better to remove the old V3 references completely and then add the V4 ones in again so ensure that the PowrShell scripts run correctly. Not sure if it totally necessary... but glad you sorted it.